# Simplifying animation F-Curves in Blender 2.8

Tags: animation, fcurves

I can’t find out how to use the Simplify Curve add-on on animation F-Curves in Blender 2.8.

I’ve activated the add-on, and in the 3D view the parameters are changeable when operated on a curve object. But when I select keyframes and activate Graph Editor ➔ Channel menu ➔ Simplify F-Curves, I can’t find the settings (Error Value) anywhere.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Hi Metin, welcome to the site. Long time no see

Comment: Hi @DuarteFarrajotaRamos! Nice to meet you again! Great to see that you're still using Blender. 

Comment: Are you also active on the Blender Artists forum? I like to visit that a few times a day.

Comment: Happy to say I'm still using Blender on a daily basis, more and more every day. I do visit BA from time to time, but not regularly. I intend to start visiting more often though

Comment: Great. Looking forward to meeting you there as well.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like unfinished implementation, but there is a workaround for the time being

Don't use the menu to call the operator, call it from the <kbd>F3</kbd> Search Menu while hovering the *3D View*, not the *F-Curve Editor*

[image]

Comment: Super, it works! A smart workaround, thanks a lot, Duarte! 

Comment: For me this addon says "upgrade to 2.8x required" in the preferences. Help?